# Limit of function on expanding intervals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

> Problem: Suppose we have a function $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} 1_{[\epsilon, \infty)} f(x) = 0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Is it true that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$? To clarify, $1_{[\epsilon, \infty)} = 1$ if $x \in [\epsilon, \infty)$, and $0$ if $x \in [0, \epsilon)$.

Attempt: It seems that I should look at the expression 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \lim_{x\to\infty} 1_{[\epsilon, \infty)} f(x)$$
but I am not very sure how to start the problem, and not even sure if the statement is in fact true. If I swap the order of limits, I feel that there might be counterexamples where $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} 1_{[\epsilon, \infty)} f(x)$ diverges? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's true.  If you're looking at the limit as $x\to\infty$ the behavior near $0,$ or any other finite value, doesn't matter.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you. But could you elaborate on this a little more? It's been some time since I've dealt with limits in detail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion I'm going to change your $\epsilon$ to $a$.

In fact, all we need to assume is that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}1_{[a,\infty)}f(x)=0$$
for one value of $a$.  Let $\epsilon>0$.  By assumption there exists $M_0$ such that if $x>M_0$ then
$$|1_{[a,\infty)}f(x)|<\epsilon\ .$$
Now choose $M=\max(a,M_0)$.  If $x>M$ then
$$|1_{[a,\infty)}f(x)|<\epsilon\quad\hbox{and}\quad 1_{[a,\infty)}f(x)=f(x)\ ,$$
so
$$|f(x)|<\epsilon\ .$$